# x509 client authentication without server authentication (SSL, HTTPS)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, https, x509

I have a spring boot application that I would like to add x509 client authentication to (in order to avoid user/password authentication). As the application is running behind a reverse proxy that already handles SSL/HTTPS I don't want to add the server authentication part.

In order to do that I followed the tutorial on Baeldung but only the client part. When I try to start the spring boot application that fails with

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SSL is enabled but no trust material is configured
```

I tried to find tutorials that only use client authentication but couldn't find any. It seems to me that it is not possible to add client authentication without server authentication as well, is it?

Comment: Yes it’s possible. You have to run the server end in client mode and the client end in server mode. Much easier to run in normal mode and have a server certificate as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info although it sounds a bit hacky. Do you have more information on that?